# Apache2 allow PHP

Tags: apache2, php

I have a new installation of Apache2 and PHP. But it seems PHP is not allowed on Apache. Server returns php as plain text. There are tons of files in /etc/apache2 directory. I dont know where to find directive to allow php. Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Please give more Details.  What version of Ubuntu are you running?  Did you do a regular install and then added the server programs?  How did you do that?  If you answer those questions people can help more.  Apache2 and PHP go together very very well.

Comment: The solution is in command sudo a2enmod php7.4. There was also some problems with some npm events package which has to be disabled first by a2dismod....

Comment: Questions must not be resolved via comments.  Please decide on a system-recognized resolution for this page -- either a question retraction or an accepted (educational) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to run a command **sudo a2enmod php7.4**. There was also some problems with npm events module which has to be disabled at first by a2dismod...